# Return the data are Max Datetime and different identity different row - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `tbl_locate` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Locating` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MainPower` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Acc` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PowerOff` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Alarm` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Speed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Direction` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MainID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IOState` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OilState` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

### SQL STRING

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_locate WHERE DateTime=(SELECT MAX(`DateTime`) FROM tbl_locate WHERE MainID=1,2,3)
```

i want to return the data which is latest row where main id are 1 or 2 or 3,
so,need to return 3 rows latest datetime.
1st row are id 1 latest datetime
second row are id 2 latest datetime
third row are id 3 latest datetime

How to do it?

Comment: There are many rows per `MainId` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT        *
FROM          tbl_locate AS a
INNER JOIN     
(
    SELECT    MainID, Max(DateTime) AS DateTime
    FROM      tbl_locate
    GROUP BY  MainID
) AS b
ON            a.MainID = b.MainID
AND           a.DateTime = b.DateTime
WHERE b.MainID in(1,2,3)
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Order it by DateTime, and get first 3 row:
      SELECT * FROM `tbl_locate` ORDER BY DateTime LIMIT 3

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_locate t
  JOIN (SELECT Max(DateTime) MaxDateTime, MainId
        FROM tbl_Locate
        WHERE MainId IN (1,2,3)
        GROUP BY MainId) t2 
   ON t.MainId = t2.MainId AND t.DateTime = t2.MaxDateTime
```

This should return you 3 rows, one each for Main ID 1,2,3 with their corresponding Max(DateTime).  However, if multiple rows exist with the same DateTime, then it will return more than one record.

Here is the sample Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2c49/1

In case multiple records exist with the same date, you need to introduce a RANK to ensure you only return a single record for each MainId:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 
   @rowNumber:= IF(@prevRow=t.MainId, @rowNumber:=@rowNumber+1, 1) rank,
  t.* , 
  @prevRow:=t.MainId
FROM tbl_locate t
  JOIN (SELECT 
        Max(DateTime) MaxDateTime, MainId
        FROM tbl_Locate
        WHERE MainId IN (1,2,3)
        GROUP BY MainId) t2 
   ON t.MainId = t2.MainId AND t.DateTime = t2.MaxDateTime
JOIN (SELECT @rowNumber:= 0) t3

 ) t
WHERE rank = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dce87/2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    T1.*
FROM tbl_locate T1
    LEFT JOIN tbl_locate T2
        ON T1.MainID = T2.MainID
          AND T1.`DateTime` < T2.`DateTime` 
WHERE T2.Id IS NULL
  AND MainID IN (1,2,3)
```